# How to delay the return to the calling function swift

Tags: swift, location, delay

In my application the user can press a button. That in turn leads to a function call which is showed below:

**In ViewController.Swift**

```
@IBAction func pickMeUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    sendPushNotificationController().sendPushNotification("sendRequest",userInfo: defaults.stringForKey("x73")!, userInf23: defaults.stringForKey("x23")! )

    locationController.getLocationForShortTime() // --> here i want the timer to finish the 5 seconds before proceeding

    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    //activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

}
```

And this is the class function where the call is being made to

**In getUserLocation.swift**

```
func initManager(){

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func getLocationForShortTime(){

    initManager()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "stopGettingLocation", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

func stopGettingLocation(){

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

So this will make the application get the users location for 5 seconds and then the timer will stop the updates. What i want to do is when the five seconds has elapsed and the location update stops THEN i would like the calling function to proceed to next line.

I though of some solutions using boolean, but it is not a nice solution. Im thinking there might be a better way to do this?

Comment: Pass the closure to `getLocationForShortTime`.  The one that should be run once the thing is finished.

Comment: Im sorry i did not understand what you ment with closure? @AntonBronnikov

Comment: Please see the answer.

Comment: You can use sleep(0.5 as UInt32) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have told you what to do, but not why.

You need to adjust your thinking.

With an event-driven device like an iPhone/iPad, you can't stop processing on the main thread for 5 seconds. The UI would lock up, and after a couple of seconds the system would kill your app as being hung.

Instead, what you do is to invoke a block of code (a closure) after a delay.

You could rewrite your function like this:

```
@IBAction func pickMeUpButton(sender: AnyObject) 
{      
  sendPushNotificationController().sendPushNotification("sendRequest",
     userInfo: defaults.stringForKey("x73")!,
     userInf23: defaults.stringForKey("x23")! )

  initManager()

  //Start the activity indicator during the delay
  activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
  self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
  activityIndicator.startAnimating()

  dispatch_after(
    dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),
    dispatch_get_main_queue())
  {
    //The code in the braces gets run after the delay value
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
  }
  //dispatch_after returns immediately, so code here will run before
  //the delay period passes.
}
```

That button action code will:

Call initManager to start the location manager running.

Immediately create an activity indicator, add it to the view controller's content view, and start it spinning.

Then, the call to dispatch_after will wait for 5 seconds before running the code in the braces, which will stop the location manger and stop the activity indicator.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you. The only thing was that the two code slices that i showed was two different classes. I changed a little to your code to make it work. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

For delaying a function-call you can use `dispatch_after`. It's syntax is a little bit ugly so you can also use this delay function:

```
/// delays the execution of the passed function
func delay(delay: Double, closure: ()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        closure)
}

// calling directly (locationManager gets captured; which is in this case negligible to consider)
delay(5.0, closure: locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation)

// or indirect through your function
delay(5.0, closure: stopGettingLocation)
```

Comment: Where exactly should i call the delay function. Also if you were to describe with words. What does this line say: delay(5.0, closure: locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation)

Comment: @TimoCengiz The delay function should be called right after the code which is executed immediately. `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation` returns a function which gets passed to the delay function and delayed by the passed number in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the closure to `getLocationForShortTime`. The one that should be run once the thing is finished.  I can't really test the code, but it's probably something like:

```
class Handler { // <- This is the wrapper class for completion closures
    private let run: Void -> Void
    init(_ run: Void -> Void) { self.run = run }
}

lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager! = self.lazyLocationManager()

func lazyLocationManager() -> CLLocationManager {
    let _locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    _locationManager.delegate = self
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    _locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    return _locationManager
}

func getLocationQuick(onComplete: Void -> Void) { // <- This takes the closure
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
        5,
        target: self,
        selector: "gotLocationQuick:",
        userInfo: Handler(onComplete),  // <- Here you wrap the completion closure
        repeats: false                  //    and pass it to the timer
    )

    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
}

func gotLocationQuick(timer: NSTimer) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let completionHandler = timer.userInfo as! Handler
    completionHandler.run()
}

@IBAction func pickMeUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    sendPushNotificationController().sendPushNotification(
        "sendRequest",
        userInfo: defaults.stringForKey("x73")!,
        userInf23: defaults.stringForKey("x23")!
    )

    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    locationController.getLocationQuick() { // <- You post the request for
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()   //    geolocation and indicate the code
    }                                       //    to be run once it's finished
}
```